# Display a new design between 6pm and 8am

Tags: php, time

Right, i'm not a huge fan of this so please don't slate me for this question as a client wants this feature...not me.

I have Design A (a light version or a website) that will be on show as normal when they go to www.example.com but at 6pm until 8am every day, the client wants to display Design B (a dark version).

Can this be done using PHP? Something along the lines of this:

```
<?php if the time right now is between 6pm and 8am { ?>
    Display Design B
<?php } else { ?>
    Display Design A
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Output a different stylesheet url in a link at the top of the page. Make this stylesheet "dark".

Comment: Are you unsure of how to have two different designs or how to display a different design for different times?

Comment: yes it can be done that way, whenever page is loaded it is going to switch the template

Comment: @Asad, I have to change inline images also.

Comment: @bendataclear The latter, I'm asking how to write the PHP that will switch my designs

Comment: @egr103 Use a variable for the name of the directory your images are stored in. Make another folder with different images. Switch this variable as well.

Comment: @Asad I've no idea how to do it, hence my question

Comment: @egr103, don't be lazy. If you've got inline IMG tags and you don't want to reimplement them in CSS then you'll need to switch on every IMG tag, which is rather messy and hence not a good idea.

Comment: @deed02392 You don't need to switch on every tag. That is what variables are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the date function to do this. But this date function will echo your server timezone. If you want time in gmt, use gmdate().

```
<?php if(date("H") > 18 && date("H") < 08 ){ ?>
    Display Design B
<?php } else { ?>
    Display Design A
<?php }?>
```

Comment: If your server is in US, then date("H") will give the current hour in US timezone. So in US if time is 20:48, it will give you 20. But if you want the hour value in gmt, you need to use gmdate(). Look my example above (if condition)

Comment: What I have noticed with your code is that it seems to be 6pm to 8PM (20:00hrs) not 6pm to 8AM (08:00hrs), which is what I was asking for. So overnight basically

Comment: Oh sorry, didnt realize that. I have changed it now. It should be 08

Comment: Shouldn't this be `if(date("H") > 18 || date("H") < 08 )` ? I don't see how it can be greater than 18 and less than 8 at the same time. It can only be either.

Answer (score 1):

I love this concept, glad to hear someone else is doing it!

Anyway, hopefully your site is designed around CSS. In which case your answer lies in switching in the correct CSS file when necessary. Beware that most browsers will cache the CSS, so use a cache defeater by adding an arbitrary argument to the request for the CSS file:

```
<?php if(date("H") >= 18 && date("H") < 8 ){ ?>
    <style src="dark.css?r=<?php echo md5(rand().microtime()); ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <style src="light.css?r=<?php echo md5(rand().microtime()); ?>" />
<?php }?>
```

Got lots of inline IMG tags? Best solution is to reimplement them in CSS. Otherwise:

```
<?php
$sheet_time = (date('H') >= 18 && date('H') < 8) ? 'dark' : 'light';
?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $sheet_time; ?>/foo.jpg" />
```

Naturally splitting up all your images into dark/light directories (which you'll need to do even if you implement in CSS anyway).

Comment: This is something but I also too need to change inline images as well as CSS. Plus I'm wanting to know what the PHP is to switch between the two designs

Comment: If the files are differently named, then there is no need for a 'cache defeater'.

Comment: Ah, are you using the IMG tag? Naughty. You should really rewrite the stylesheets so that all the images are displayed due to CSS. This makes for better behaviour in more browsers, too.

Comment: @Sammitch This is generally correct, however the only way to guarantee the browser loads a fresh copy of the CSS is to do this. Especially whilst the guy is testing and probably making constant edits and expecting F5 to reload his edits.

Comment: I would not do this rand() business in production. Horrible idea. For development only maybe but whats wrong with hitting CTRL F5 or having your cache disabled during development. And btw Sammitch is right, differently named files are best, INCLUDING renaming your updated images or the folder they are in to ensure cache busting OR use a revision system using mod rewrite or something like `/css/r20/style.css` or `/css/style.css?r=20`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Isle_of_Man");
$imgfolder = "standard";
if(intval(date('H')) >= 18 || intval(date('H')) <= 8){ 
    $imgfolder = "dark";
    ?>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dark.css" />
<?
}else{ 
    $imgfolder = "standard";
    ?>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="standard.css" />
<?
}
```

To load images, you can use:

```
<img src = "images/<?echo $imgfolder; ?>/header.jpg"...
```

Your images should be stored in `images/standard/` and `images/dark` respectively.

Comment: How do I change this for gmt time zone (aka London time)?

Comment: @egr103 Add `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Isle_of_Man");` to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted specific images to change, I'd maybe use a function,

```
<?php
function chooseImage($image1, $image2){
    if(date("H") >= 8 && date("H") < 18 ){ ?>
        return '<img src="'.$image1.'" alt="Daytime Image" \>';
    <?php } else { ?>
    return '<img src="'.$image2.'" alt="Nighttime Image" \>';
<?php }?>
```

Put that somewhere in your page, then wherever you wanted an image to change you could simple call the function and pass on the 2 images that will change as variables:

```
<?php chooseImage(image1.jpg,image2.jpg);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$hour = (int) date('H');
if (($hour > 8 && $hour < 18)) {
    // it's past 8 AM and less then 6 PM
    $daytime_design = true;
    $resource_path = 'day';
}
else {
    // the other hours, 6 PM to 8 AM the next day
    $daytime_design = false;
    $resource_path = 'night';
}
?>
```

Much later in our template.tpl.php or whatever

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/<?=$resource_path;?>/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php 
if ($daytime_design === true) {
    echo 'Good Day!';
}

if ($daytime_design === false) {
    echo 'Only shows for night design, <img src="special-night-image.jpg">';
}

?>

This will show /images/day/logo.jpg or /images/night/logo.jpg
<img src="/images/<?=$resource_path;?>/logo.jpg"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this grabbing the servers time? How do I alter this to work based on UK time?

Comment: Yes it grabs the server time. You can set your timezone though with `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`. I've edited answer.